# How to write a k8s controller that watches and reconciles arbitrary resources?

Tags: kubernetes

I'd like to write a k8s controller that reads a list of resources from its configuration and then watches all of the specified resources and backs them up into an external data storage whenever they are changed.

For this, I have to dynamically register the watches. Note that the resources to be watched are known when the controller is started, so I don't have to add further watches during runtime.

I found [this example](https://firehydrant.com/blog/dynamic-kubernetes-informers/), which is already pretty close to what I want to achieve.
However, I was wondering whether I could use the [controller-runtime](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/controller-runtime) for this. I have already built k8s controllers using the controller-runtime and like the general look & feel, although I mostly copy-pasted the stuff together from other projects and don't have a deep understanding on how the controller-runtime actually works.

I understood that I can add watches for arbitrary resources to a [Controller](https://pkg.go.dev/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/controller). But a `Controller` is tied to a single `Reconciler`, whose `Reconcile` method only gets name and namespace. This means a `Reconciler` - and therefore a `Controller` - can only be responsible for a single kind of resource, as there is no way to tell the `Reconcile` method which kind of resource triggered the event, correct? So, to achieve my goal using the controller-runtime, I would have to create multiple `Controller`s, one for each kind of resource that is configured for backup?

Can/should I create an arbitrary amount of `Controller`s or does this have some undesirable side effects? Is the controller-runtime simply not meant for this use-case and I should do it like in the linked example instead?

**To sum this up: What is the 'nicest'/'most idiomatic' way of building a k8s controller which can not only react to changes to a configurable set of resources, but is also able to identify the resource which triggered the event?**